# Assigning value in C macro

Tags: c, macros

Is it ok to assign a value in a C macro (i.e. have an lvalue in a macro)? For example, I would like to set a bit of a number to `1` based on the specified bit position. Is it ok to do this:

```
#define SET_BIT(data, pos)  ((data) |= (1U << (pos)))
```

I've tested this and it works, but I feel like I'm walking on thin ice here and if I get used to macros like this, I would eventually run into problems.

Comment: Regarding the case of bit manipulation specifically, using function-like macros to invent a private macro language is a horrible idea. This code should have been written as `data |= 1U << pos;` without the macro, which is already as readable as it gets. The macro added absolutely nothing but obfuscation.

Comment: @Lundin I agree. I simplified the macro for the sake of the question. In the original code, it's used for more complex bit manipulation done multiple times and adding a macro makes the code more readable and understandable.

Comment: If the code really is complex then write a function, not a macro.

Comment: @Lundin Not relevant for this question.

Comment: Well it is, because a function has type safety but this macro hasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros won't exist once the preprocessor has finished expanding them in the code. If you have a statement like

```
SET_BIT(some_data, some_pos);
```

then it will be replaced by

```
((some_data) |= (1U << (some_pos)));
```

in the code that is parsed and compiled.

In short, doing assignments in macros is perfectly fine.

---

The problem with the first `SET_BIT_TO_VAL` macro:

```
#define SET_BIT_TO_VAL(data, pos, val)  (CLEAR_BIT(data, pos); (data) |= (1U << (pos)))
```

is that you put statements inside parentheses, like they were expressions. So that will not build.

The common way to group statements in a macro is to wrap them in a `do { ... } while(0)` loop:

```
#define SET_BIT_TO_VAL(data, pos, val) \
    do {                               \
        CLEAR_BIT(data, pos);          \
        SET_BIT(data, pos);            \
    } while (0)
```

Comment: One more question, how would you chain two assignment macros? For example, if I have a macro that clears a bit: `#define CLEAR_BIT(data, pos)  ((data) &= ~(1U << (pos)))` and want to clear a bit and then set a bit in another macro, there is a problem with parentheses: `#define SET_BIT_TO_VAL(data, pos, val)  (CLEAR_BIT(data, pos); (data) |= (1U << (pos)))`. Is it ok to put the macro in curly braces in that case, like this: `#define SET_BIT_TO_VAL(data, pos, val)  {CLEAR_BIT(data, pos); (data) |= (1U << (pos));}` ?

Comment: @A6SE Updated answer to help you with the comment.